# the distance tends to be one, but I want the distance to tend to be another

Tags: java, netbeans, gui-builder

When I'm positioning textareas on the screen (with the gui-builder of netbeans), the distance between the first and the second tends to be one (18 pixels), the distance between the second and the third tends to be one too (18 pixels too), but I want both distances to tend to be another (25 pixels). How to do that?

Comment: I have just found "Before NetBeans 6, the Free Design layout manager supported a single preferred gap for component placement. In 6.0, three preferred gaps are supported. A preferred gap is the preferred spacing between components, and is available on all sides of a component for quick and elegant placement, as shown in Figure 8. For developers who may like more control over spacing between components, having three choices comes in handy." at http://www.netbeans.org/community/magazine/html/03/matisse/

How I wish it was customizable.

Comment: I found it! Space Around Component!! In the context menu!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn how to use LayoutManagers and don't rely on an IDE to do the layout for you.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html)